# how to trace or get evidence you've been hacked

Tags: network, email, wifi, server, iphone

my devices and my network have been compromised. I foolishly left my router unprotected
and they were able to gain access to all my apple devices and then install some sort of software that will take pictures and record audio and store them in their metadata so it remains hidden on my computer. This person has then set up a page and has leaked my personal pics & is spreading terrible rumors about me .......can anyone help me out...with the specifics on how this is done. So I can build a case against this person .....its gotten so bad that there saying I'm some sort of child predator and diseased pervert.

Answer (score 1):

Your first priority: repression. Make sure that your security is tight and no more information is leaked.

Second priority: repair. Don't try to fight the criminal yourself. Go to the police and report a crime. Most police forces have a digital forensic team that can do the things needed. Let's just hope that they have the time/resources/priority to look into your case.